# Emitting signals causes core dumps

Tags: python, multithreading, pyside, signals-slots, coredump

Being (quite) new to both Python and Qt I'm fiddling with this code.
It might be somewhat messy but I've tried to shave the code down as much as possible and still get the core-dumps.

Basically there's a button to start "something" - now it's just a for-loop - 
a progress bar, and a label.

Clicking the button in the interface outputs 1 to the console and then core-dumps. No data is seen in either the progress bar or the label.

I am using Python 2.7.11, Qt-4.8.7 and PySide 1.2.2.

The threaded code is from this youtube vid:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ivcxZSHL7jM

I've tried placing the emitting lines outside the loop, even into the MainDialog class, and it seems that as soon as the emitting signal comes from outside the MainDialog class, it crashes. It only works inside MainDialog (using static integers for testing purposes, tested after the progressbar reset).

showGui.py - nothing wrong here - (made with designer and converted with pyside):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'show.ui'
#
# Created: Wed Jul 13 09:10:12 2016
#      by: pyside-uic 0.2.15 running on PySide 1.2.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_mainDialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, mainDialog):
        mainDialog.setObjectName("mainDialog")
        mainDialog.resize(369, 171)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(mainDialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 40, 84, 33))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.progressBar = QtGui.QProgressBar(mainDialog)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 110, 231, 23))
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(mainDialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 40, 81, 31))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(mainDialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(mainDialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, mainDialog):
        mainDialog.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("mainDialog", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("mainDialog", "Button", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("mainDialog", "TextLabel", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

test.py - this fails when emitting the signals:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys
import time
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

import showGui
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *


class MainDialog(QDialog, showGui.Ui_mainDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.threadclass = ThreadClass()
        self.connect(self.threadclass, QtCore.SIGNAL('GFX_PROGRESS'), self.setProgress)
        self.connect(self.threadclass, QtCore.SIGNAL('TEXT_PROGRESS'), self.setTextLabel)
        self.connect(self.pushButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.threadclass.doSomething)
        self.progressBar.reset()


    def setTextLabel(self, val):
        self.label.setText(val)

    def setProgress(self, val):
        self.progressBar.setValue(val)


class ThreadClass(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ThreadClass, self).__init__(parent)

    def doSomething(self):
        self.runcmd()
        # some more code here

    def runcmd(self):
        for i in range(1, 100):
            print("Status at : %s " % i)

            # this one crashes
            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('TEXT_PROGRESS'), i)

            # this one crashes too
            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('GFX_PROGRESS'), i)
            time.sleep(1)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = MainDialog()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: You should try to use [new style signals](https://wiki.qt.io/Signals_and_Slots_in_PySide). they are much less error prone and if you do something wrong they usually trigger an exception instead of crashing the program. So you should define in your class a `QtCore.Signal` and then use `self.the_signal.emit()` and connect it using `self.threadclass.the_signal.connect(self.the_slot)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use the [old-style signal and slot syntax](http://wiki.qt.io/Signals_and_Slots_in_PySide). It's bug-prone, and does not raise an exception if you get it wrong. In addition to that, it looks like the implementation is somewhat broken in PySide. I converted your code example to PyQt4, and it does not dump core.

To get your example working in PySide, you first need to switch to the new-style signal and slot syntax. Also, your current threading implementation is wrong. It doesn't actually start the worker thread, so the all the code will run in the main thread, and it will block the gui.

The following fixes should get the example working as expected:

```
class MainDialog(QDialog, Ui_mainDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        ..
        # use new-style connections
        self.threadclass.gfxProgress.connect(self.setProgress)
        self.threadclass.textProgress.connect(self.setTextLabel)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.threadclass.doSomething)   


class ThreadClass(QtCore.QThread):
    # define new-style signals
    gfxProgress = QtCore.Signal(int)
    textProgress = QtCore.Signal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ThreadClass, self).__init__(parent)

    def doSomething(self):
        # start the thread
        # by default, this will automatically call run()
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        for i in range(1, 100):
            print("Status at : %s " % i)
            # emit the new-style signals
            self.gfxProgress.emit(i)
            self.textProgress.emit(str(i))
            time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much (I thought I did use the new signals of pyside). A small issue I ran into with your example was that ***Signal*** isn't defined. It's ***pyqtSignal*** as referenced [here] (http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html)  can you edit your example to reflect this please?

Comment: @CarstenJensen. Your question is all related to PySide, so I don't think it would be right to change it now. Anyway, it's only a minor difference in syntax - the code is otherwise exactly the same.

Comment: I took your example, implemented it with mine, converted mine to PyQT, this was where I found the problem with ***Signal*** not being found, but ***pyqtSignal*** works for PyQT. And since your example is PyQT, for future reference newbies like myself wouldn't have problems using your example... I hope you know where I'm getting at :-)

Comment: @CarstenJensen. You have misunderstood. The code in my answer is for PySide, not PyQt. If you add those changes to your original PySide example, it will work. There is no need to switch to PyQt. In the first part of my answer, I showed that using old-style signal syntax seems to be the cause of the problem. I tested this by converting your original example to PyQt4 (but only making the most minimal of changes). The PyQt4 version did not dump core, which suggests there may be a bug in PySide. But anyway, you can easily avoid that bug by using new-style signals (as I showed in my example code).

Comment: Ah, I understand. "I converted your code example to PyQt4, and it does not dump core."  I thought this sentence meant for the code example you gave. Sorry about the confusion. Once again, thanks alot for your help :-)